# how to rewrite the recursive solution to iterative one

Tags: recursion, iteration

The problem is derive from OJ. 
The description is :
We are playing the Guess Game. The game is as follows:
I pick a number from 1 to n. You have to guess which number I picked.
Every time you guess wrong, I'll tell you whether the number I picked is higher or lower.
However, when you guess a particular number x, and you guess wrong, you pay $x. You win the game when you guess the number I picked.
Given a particular n ≥ 1, find out how much money you need to have to guarantee a win.

I write small snippet about MinMax problem in recursion. But it is slow and I want to rewrite it in a iterative way. Could anyone help with that and give me the idea about how you convert the recursive solution to iterative one? Any idea is appreciated. The code is showed below:

```
   public int getMoneyAmount(int n) {
        int[][] dp = new int[n + 1][n + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < dp.length; i++)
            Arrays.fill(dp[i], -1);
        return solve(dp, 1, n);
    }
    private int solve(int[][] dp, int left, int right){
        if(left >= right){
            return 0;
        }
        if(dp[left][right] != -1){
            return dp[left][right];
        }
        dp[left][right] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = left; i <= right; i++){
            dp[left][right] = Math.min(dp[left][right], i + Math.max(solve(dp, left, i - 1),solve(dp, i + 1, right)));
        }
        return dp[left][right];
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what it is exactly that you're trying to do. It seems like a complex dance of multi dimenion arrays, but without further clarification or inline comments I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you convert using some focused concepts:

- Replace the recursion with a **while** loop -- or a **for** loop, if you can pre-determine how many iterations you need (which you *can* do in this case).
- Within the loop, check for the recursion's termination conditions; when you hit one of those, skip the rest of the loop.
- Maintain local variables to replace the parameters and return value.
- The loop termination is completion of the *entire* problem.  In your case, this would be filling out the entire **dp** array.
- The loop body consists of the computations that are currently in your recursion step: preparing the arguments for the recursive call.

Your general approach is to step through a nested (2-D) loop to fill out your array, starting from the simplest cases (left = right) and working your way to the far corner (left = 1, right = n).  Note that your main diagonal is 0 (initialize that before you get into the loop), and your lower triangle is unused (don't even bother to initialize it).

For the loop body, you should be able to derive how to fill in each succeeding diagonal (one element shorter in each iteration) from the one you just did.  That assignment statement is the body.  In this case, you don't need the recursion termination conditions: the one that returns 0 is what you cover in initialization; the other you never hit, controlling **left** and **right** with your loop indices.

Are these enough hints to get you moving?